# Exit menuitem is not working in internal frame

Tags: java, swing

See this [Screenshot](http://postimg.org/image/qto63wp65/).

I just want that when user  ENTER  exit menu item frame is closed. i have tried with action performed and keypressed event   but none are working .
with `this .dispose` and `system.exit(0);`

AND EXIT MENU  SHOULD BE CLOSED BY ENTER KEY

When I used:

```
private void jMenu2MenuKeyPressed(javax.swing.event.MenuKeyEvent evt) {                                      

        System.out.println("erygr444eyh3443");
}
```

It works for all menu items

Second approach:

```
private void jMenu2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    System.out.println("erygreyh");
    if (evt.getSource() == jMenu2) //exit
    {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

it doesn't work.

Third approach:

```
private void jMenu10KeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                   
   System.out.println("sfgd4r7y648hh6889");
}
```

It works for all menu items.

http://postimg.org/image/qto63wp65/

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please check the [FAQ - How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask good questions, so that you get good answers. Please especially take the effort to properly format your question - otherwise people will simply skip it or downvote it. This time, since it is your first question, I did it for you. Also, please describe **what** does not work - if you simply write "it does not work" we have no idea of what the issue is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using Netbeans GUI Builder. With this said, it looks like you have the listener on the auto-generated `JMenu` code. You instead want it on the `jMenuItem`Make sure that you right-click the `jMenuItem` (from the design view) and not the `jMenu` when you add the listener.

Also make sure to add `ActionListener`s and not `KeyListener`

If right click on the `jMenuItem` (and not the `jMenu`) and add an `actionPerformed`, this code will be auto-generated

```
private void jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
}
```

Do you see the difference from your code? you have `jMenuXActionPerformed`, which means the listener was added to the `JMenu` and not the `JMenuItem`.

Also make sure it's `JMenuItem` your adding to the `JMenu`s and not more `JMenu`s

[image]
[image]
[image]

---

**UPDATE** to OP comment.

1. Click on the `File` `JMenuItem` in the design view. While it's highlighted in orange,
2. Click on the properties tab to the very right of NetBeans.
3. You'll See a property that says `mnemonic`. Type in `F`
4. You should see a line under the `F` now on the `File` `JMenu`
5. Drag a `JMenuItem` to the `File` `JMenu` and add an `actionPerformed` to it.
6. In the auto-generated method, but your `Sysem.exit()`

Now when you run the program, press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> and the menu will pop up. Press down till you get to the `JMenuItem` that exits the program and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

That should be about what you're looking for

---

If you want to add an accelorator, just double click on the while little text box the says `shortcut` and you can select what the short cut is for the `jMenuItem`. You can add Ctrl mask with another key. There are many possible combination for you to choose from

[image]

Comment: and how could i exit on  pressing  exit menu by pressing enter key and which event should i used.

Comment: Why you you want to do that? If the `JMenuItem` is in view and you press enter the event should be fired.

Comment: thanks sr i got this but  if there is another menu (example say:EXIT) next to edit  and similary  i have to  apply same procedure on menu (EXIT)also . can u give some suggestions.

Comment: Add the `EXIT` `JMenu`. You Then need to add a `JMenuItem` to it. Add the `actionPerformed`. Then add the `accelorator` to the `JMenuItem`, not the `JMenu`, as shown in the bottom picture.

Comment: i just want to ask  sr that  when user Press Enter Key on (EXIT) JMENU. without adding jmenuitems. system is totaly closed. i have tried action performed but no event is firing on enter(Exit Jmenu). neither keypresssed. IF its possible ad how could i do that.

Comment: What don't you understand about my directions? You need to set the binding to a `JMenuItem`! It wont work on a `JMenu`

Comment: That's why you should have the `Exit` in the `File` menu like all other programs. And set an accelerator for it, like `CTRL + ENTER` or whatever you want it to be

Answer (score 0):

```
private void menuExitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

        System.exit(0);


}
```

Using ActionPerformed rather than KeyPressed will solve your problem